# Shooting not working with ArrayList Java 2D Platformer

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have never tried to implement shooting in any kind of game before and when I try to remove and element of the ArrayList I'm using it throws and index out of bounds exception. I want to be able to press the enter key, store the current direction that the player is facing and then shoot a projectile in that current direction. Then, once a projectile has reached its destination to remove itself from the ArrayList and not be rendered anymore. However, when it reaches the end of the map (x == Map.mapSizeX), the bullet freezes and that's when the exception is thrown. **(Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1)**.

## Code for the shooting class (Projectile.java)

```
package Engine;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Projectile {

public static ArrayList<Integer> bullets = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);
private static DirectionalVector dir = new DirectionalVector();
private static int index = 0;
private static int x,y;

public Projectile(int direction, int x, int y){
    dir.applyDirection(direction);
    bullets.add(index);
    index += 1;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void updatePos(){
    if (dir.right){
        x += 1;
        dir.left = false;
        dir.down = false;
    }
    if (dir.left){
        x -= 1;
        dir.right = false;
        dir.down = false;
    }
    if (dir.down){
        y += 1;
        dir.left = false;
        dir.right = false;
    }
    if (dir.down){
        System.out.println("DOWN");
    }
    if (dir.right){
        System.out.println("RIGHT");
    }
    if (dir.left){
        System.out.println("LEFT");
    }

    if (x > Map.mapSizeX){
        bullets.remove(index);
    }

    if (x < 0){
        bullets.remove(index);
    }

    if (y > Map.mapSizeY){
        bullets.remove(index);
    }

    if (y < 0){
        bullets.remove(index);
    }
}

public static void render(Graphics2D g2){
    int r = new Random().nextInt(256);
    int g = new Random().nextInt(256);
    int b = new Random().nextInt(256);
    if (r < 50){
        r = new Random().nextInt(256);
    }
    if (g < 50){
        g = new Random().nextInt(256);
    }
    if (b < 50){
        b = new Random().nextInt(256);
    }
    g2.setColor(new Color(r,g,b));
    g2.fillRect(x * Map.tileSize, y * Map.tileSize, Map.tileSize, Map.tileSize);
}
```

## Code for the DirectionalVector class

```
package Engine;

public class DirectionalVector {

public boolean left = false, right = true, down = false;

public DirectionalVector(){

}

public void applyDirection(int id){
    if (id == 0){
        right = true;
    }
    if (id == 1){
        left = true;
    }
    if (id == 2){
        down = true;
    }
}

}
```

## Code for the Player class

```
package Engine;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Player implements KeyListener, Runnable{
public static int x = 0,y = 0;
private static boolean right = false, left = false, falling = false, jumping = false;
private Thread thread = new Thread(this, "GAME LOOP");
private static int lastDirectionPressed = 0;
public static Projectile bullet;

public Player(){
    thread.start();
}

public void renderPlayer(boolean value, Graphics2D g2){
    if (value){
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillRect(x * Map.tileSize, y * Map.tileSize, Map.tileSize, Map.tileSize);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int c = e.getKeyCode();

    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && right){
        x += 1;
        lastDirectionPressed = 0;
    }

    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && left){
        x -= 1;
        lastDirectionPressed = 1;
    }

    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && jumping){
        y -= 1;
    }

    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        bullet = new Projectile(lastDirectionPressed, x, y);
    }
}

public void update(){
    if (x != Map.mapSizeX){
        right = Map.getTile(x + 1, y) == 0;
    }

    if (x > 0){
        left = Map.getTile(x - 1, y) == 0;
    }

    if (x == 0){
        left = false;
    }

    if (x == Map.mapSizeX){
        right = false;
    }

    if (y != Map.mapSizeY){
        falling = Map.getTile(x, y + 1) == 0;
    }

    if (y == Map.mapSizeY){
        falling = false;
    }

    if (falling){
        y += 1;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void run(){
    while (true){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
            update();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

## Code for the ContentPane class (Where all the rendering occurs)

```
package Engine;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings({"serial", "static-access"})
public class ContentPane extends JPanel{

    private Map map = new Map();
    public Player player = new Player();

    public ContentPane(){

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2);
        map.renderMap(true, g2);
        player.renderPlayer(true, g2);
        if (player.bullet.bullets.size() > 0){
            player.bullet.updatePos();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < player.bullet.bullets.size(); i++){
            player.bullet.render(g2);
        }

        System.out.println(player.bullet.bullets.size());
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where *exactly* is the exception thrown? What does the stack trace look like? Can you try to reduce the code to a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Is `Map` one of your own classes? Seeing how `new Map()` will give you a compilation otherwise. And also, while people are helping you with your issue, I seriously think you need to look into **dependency injection**. I think wikipedia even has a good article on it. You're **way** overusing `static` fields, and for the wrong reasons mostly.